# Is Jensen's covering lemma meaningful in a platonist's view?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, inner-model-theory, constructibility

The typical applications of fine structure theory are finding out the lower bounds of consistency strength of axiom systems. In such a proccess, we also constructs many combinatorial objects in core models, such as diamonds, squares, morasses and their variations.

In a platonist's view, these don't only prove the lower bounds of consistency strengths, but also constructs objects in a more realistic world, so they are in some sense more objective truth.

However, there is a kind of fine structure results, the covering lemmas, they says something like "if the (platonisticly fake) world satisfies some property, then it constains a big core model". So it talks about the property of a platonisticly fake world. Is there some natural way to convert a covering lemma into a property of a core model?

Comment: Even if $0^\#$ exists, there are inner models in which it doesn't. Jensen's covering lemma tells you something about such a model: each of its uncountable sets of ordinals can be covered by a constructible set of the same cardinality.